# Hardware needed for iOS 7 iBeacon?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, ios7, ibeacon

I am looking to develop some apps that will take advantage of iBeacon in my business, but need to first know what all hardware I will need and where I can get it from to utilize this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pre-order some beacons from [estimote](http://estimote.com).

If you want to develop your own custom hardware, I would suggest to use a [BLE mini](http://redbearlab.com/blemini/) prototyping board from RedBearLab with their [iBeacon firmware](http://redbearlab.com/ibeacon/).

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to build iBeacon-aware iOS apps, all you really need is an iBeacon.

You can get an [iBeacon Development Kit](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/ibeacon-development-kit.html) from Radius Networks that ships right away.  They also have an [iBeacon Virtual Machine](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/virtual.html) that you can run under VirtualBox with a Linux-compatible Bluetooth LE dongle.

Comment: Hate to bother you with this, given how helpful you've been with iBeacon information, but you should probably disclose that you work at Radius Networks for purposes of transparency.

Comment: Indeed, I do work for Radius Networks!  And if you order one of the iBeacon Development Kits, I'm probably the guy who will be assembling it and dropping it in the mail.  So you know where to find me!

Comment: I just posted a blog of how you can build your own iBeacon using less than $100 in parts.  http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/10/09/how-to-make-an-ibeacon-out-of-a-raspberry-pi.html

Answer (score 2):

Your iPhone can also works as iBeacon, The Hardware needed for the application totally depends on the purpose of your project. If your app needs to notify for region(needs for permanent work) then should purchase some iBeacon from estimote or radius networks or any other whichever is suitable for you. But if you need iBeacon for short time and also portable, then you can keep your iPhone as iBeacon for temporary use.